# Three.js how to set up a div as a canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to include this specific example of a three.js canvas in a div: https://codepen.io/PedalsUp/pen/qBqvvzR

How is it possible to change the javascript so that the scene will be contained in a specific div?

My aim is to be able to include it in a website as background of a section...

*(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.)*

Thank you

```
var SEPARATION = 40, AMOUNTX = 130, AMOUNTY = 35;
var container;
var camera, scene, renderer;


if (window.WebGLRenderingContext){
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
}
else {
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
}


var particles, particle, count = 0;

var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

init();
animate();

function init() {

container = document.createElement( 'div' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
if(container) {
    container.className += container.className ? ' waves' : 'waves';
}

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 120, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.y = 200; //changes how far back you can see i.e the particles towards horizon
camera.position.z = 350; //This is how close or far the particles are seen


camera.rotation.x = 0.45;

scene = new THREE.Scene();

particles = new Array();

var PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {

    color: 0x661DEE, //changes color of particles
    program: function ( context ) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc( 0, 0, 0.1, 0, PI2, true );
        context.fill();

    }

} );

var i = 0;

for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

    for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

        particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Sprite( material );
        particle.position.x = ix * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTX * SEPARATION ) / 2 );
        particle.position.z = iy * SEPARATION - ( ( AMOUNTY * SEPARATION ) - 10 );
        scene.add( particle );

    }

}

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
renderer.setClearColor( 0x090a11, 1);
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

function onWindowResize() {

windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function animate() {

requestAnimationFrame( animate );

render();

}

function render() {

var i = 0;

for ( var ix = 0; ix < AMOUNTX; ix ++ ) {

    for ( var iy = 0; iy < AMOUNTY; iy ++ ) {

        particle = particles[ i++ ];
        particle.position.y = ( Math.cos( ( ix + count ) * 0.5 ) * 20 ) + ( Math.cos( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) * 20 );
        particle.scale.x = particle.scale.y = ( Math.cos( ( ix + count ) * 0.3 ) + 2 ) * 4 + ( Math.cos( ( iy + count ) * 0.5 ) + 1 ) * 4;

    }

}

renderer.render( scene, camera );

// This increases or decreases speed
count += 0.1;

}
```

Comment: Why not use `WebGLRenderer()`?

Answer (score 0):

The code does create the rendering canvas inside of `div#waves`.  But it's code written for an old version of three.js.  (It's written for r68, but three.js is at r139 presently.)
To make it work, at a minimum, you'll need to replace these lines

```js
if (window.WebGLRenderingContext){
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
}
else {
  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
}
```

with

```js
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
```

and delete

```
renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

because `CanvasRenderer` was removed in an intermediate version of three.js.
You'll also need to replace

```js
var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( ... );
```

with

```js
var material = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( ... );
```

for the same reason.

For what it's worth, the line that places the renderer into `div#waves` is

```js
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination. I understood a few things that I wasn't even cosidering, starting from the fact that it was already rendered inside a div. I will surely need to learn three.js... I have to say that I have tried to implement the changes you told me to do, but for the moment I will keep the older version because it brakes the styling.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as such.  If you need help with the styling issue, I'll keep an eye out for a new question.